# Why isn't the value passed to another component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have several components. I pass the value from the "StepOne" component to the "stepTwo" component and this is what I get:

[image]

and I want to get this:

[image]

Here is my code:

**//stepOne. html**

```
<template>
<div if:true={showStepOne}>
    <div role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Work Type</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiNameWorkType} onsuccess={handleSuccessOne}>
                    <lightning-messages>
                    </lightning-messages>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={NAME_WORK_TYPE}>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={DESCRIPTION_WORK_TYPE}>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={ESTIMATED_DURATION_WORK_TYPE}>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={DURATION_TYPE_WORK_TYPE}>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name={AUTO_CREATE_APPT} type="checkbox" checked>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-button
                            class="slds-float_right"
                            variant="brand"
                            type="submit"
                            label="Next">
                        </lightning-button>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</div>
<c-step-two
    show-step-two={showStepTwo}
    work-type-id={workTypeID}>
</c-step-two>
```

**//stepOne. js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import WORK_TYPE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/WorkType';
import NAME_WORK_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/WorkType.Name';
import DESCRIPTION_WORK_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/WorkType.Description';
import ESTIMATED_DURATION_WORK_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/WorkType.EstimatedDuration';
import DURATION_TYPE_WORK_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/WorkType.DurationType';
import AUTO_CREATE_APPT from '@salesforce/schema/WorkType.ShouldAutoCreateSvcAppt';

export default class StepOne extends LightningElement {

    @api showStepOne;
    @api objectApiNameWorkType = WORK_TYPE_OBJECT;
    NAME_WORK_TYPE = NAME_WORK_TYPE;
    DESCRIPTION_WORK_TYPE = DESCRIPTION_WORK_TYPE;
    ESTIMATED_DURATION_WORK_TYPE = ESTIMATED_DURATION_WORK_TYPE;
    DURATION_TYPE_WORK_TYPE = DURATION_TYPE_WORK_TYPE;
    AUTO_CREATE_APPT = AUTO_CREATE_APPT;
    workTypeID;
    showStepTwo;

    handleShowStepOne(){
        if(!this.showStepOne){
            this.showStepOne = true;
        } else {
            this.showStepOne = false;
        }
    }

    handleSuccessOne(event) {
        this.workTypeID = event.detail.id;
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Work Type created",
            message: "Record ID: " + this.workTypeID,
            variant: "success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        this.handleShowStepOne();
        this.showStepTwo = true;
    }
}
```

**//stepTwo. html**

```
    <template>
    <div if:true={showStepTwo}>
        <div role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Skill Requirement</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiNameSkillRequirement} onsuccess={handleSuccessTwo}>
                        <lightning-messages>
                        </lightning-messages>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={RELATED_RECORD_ID} value={workTypeID}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={SKILL_ID}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={SKILL_LEVEL}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                            <lightning-button
                                class="slds-float_right"
                                variant="brand"
                                type="submit"
                                label="Next">
                            </lightning-button>
                    </lightning-record-edit-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </div>
    <c-step-three show-step-three={showStepThree}></c-step-three>
</template>
```

**//stepTwo. js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import SKILL_REQUIREMENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/SkillRequirement';
import RELATED_RECORD_ID from '@salesforce/schema/SkillRequirement.RelatedRecordId';
import SKILL_ID from '@salesforce/schema/SkillRequirement.SkillId';
import SKILL_LEVEL from '@salesforce/schema/SkillRequirement.SkillLevel';

export default class StepTwo extends LightningElement {
    @api showStepTwo;
    @api objectApiNameSkillRequirement = SKILL_REQUIREMENT_OBJECT;
    RELATED_RECORD_ID = RELATED_RECORD_ID;
    SKILL_ID = SKILL_ID;
    SKILL_LEVEL = SKILL_LEVEL;
    @api workTypeID;
    showStepThree;

    handleShowStepTwo(){
        if(!this.showStepTwo){
            this.showStepTwo = true;
        } else {
            this.showStepTwo = false;
        }
    }

    handleSuccessTwo(event) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Skill Requirement filled in",
            message: "Record ID: " + event.detail.id,
            variant: "success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        this.handleShowStepTwo();
        this.showStepThree = true;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think workTypeID in stepOne. js should have @api property to make it public. Could you please try that.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It would be strange, because if you look more closely, I pass the value `showStepTwo` in the same way and it works without the `@api`.

Answer (score 0):

Without going through all your code, I would suggest you change your approach to having a container component, where you store your "global" variables, which you can then use to pass on to other components, something similar to the following:

Container Component

```
<template>
  <template if:true={stepOne}>
      <c-step-one stuff={stuffToPass} oncomplete={handleCompleteStep}></c-step-one>
  </template>
  <template if:true={stepTwo}>
      <c-step-one stuff={stuffToPass} oncomplete={handleCompleteStep}></c-step-one>
  </template>
  <template if:true={stepThree}>
      <c-step-one stuff={stuffToPass} oncomplete={handleCompleteStep}></c-step-one>
  </template>
</template>
```

Currently, all I see is a mix of html with steps in between, which make your code a bit hard to follow, and your variable tracking a mess.

In your container all, you will want a public property which you constantly update when each step succeeds

container.js

```
export default class Container extends LightningElement {
    @api stuffToPAss

    handleCompleteStep(event){
        this.stuffToPAss = //udpate accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I originally wanted to implement it this way, but since I'm a beginner, I didn't succeed. Could you describe in more detail for my code?

Comment: It turns out that from "StepOne" I need to return a value to "container", which I then have to pass to "stepTwo" and from it again I need to return another value back to "container"...

Comment: yes, that is the idea, everything that needs to be passed down/shared between components, needs to be send to the parent container using an event. so the data propagates evenly across dependencies.